# How do I re-write this Objective-C line into Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

```
yourLabelName.text = [[NSString] stringWithFormat:@"The number of votes for Crepes is %d", voteCount1["votes"]];
```

I'm trying to re-write the above line of code into Swift, as it's currently written in Objective-C.  For the sake of context, I'm trying to retrieve a value in my Parse database under the column header "VoteCount", which happens to be the class name.  Here's the variable that includes all the columns:

```
    var voteCount1 = PFObject(className: "VoteCount")
    voteCount1["votes"] = 0
    voteCount1["optionName"] = "crepes"
```

Comment: labelName.text = NSString(format:"The number of votes for Crepes is %d"",voteCount1["votes"])

Answer (score 1):

***updated answer:***

taking Thilo's comment into account... how about:

```
var voteCount1 = PFObject(className: "VoteCount")
let optionName = voteCount1["optionName"];
let votes      = voteCount1["votes"] as String;

yourNameLabel.text = "The number of votes for \(optionName) is \(votes)"
```

*original answer:*

I think it should be something like:

```
var voteCount1 = PFObject(className: "VoteCount")
yourNameLabel.text = 
   "The number of votes for \(voteCount1["optionName"]) is \(voteCount1["votes"])"
```

Comment: The only problem with that is that the quotation marks within the brackets conflict with the quotation marks outside the entire quote.  XCode doesn't seem to be able to distinguish them, and I've tried writing the code in several different orders.

Comment: You can avoid that problem and increase legibility by having two more `let` to store optionName and votes.

Comment: Did you just stick that extra line with "yourNameLabel.text" under the var voteCount1 = PFObject(className: "VoteCount") with all the other variables?

Answer (score 0):

The Swift `String` type has an initializer just like the `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` factory method:

```
yourLabelName.text = String(format: "The number of votes for Crepes is %d", voteCount1["votes"])
```

Comment: You might want to cast `voteCount1["votes"]` to `NSNumber` or `Int`?

Comment: @rintaro: It matches what the OP's code says. If the OP's code is correct, then `voteCount1["votes"]` is already an `int`

Comment: `String(format:"%@", voteCount1["votes"] as NSNumber)` is OK, and also `(format:"%d", voteCount1["votes"] as Int)`. But **not** `(format:"%d", voteCount1["votes"])`, because `subscript` of `PFObject` returns `AnyObject!` it is actually a `NSNumber` in this case. It has 2 problems 1) It makes the compiler confuse with `init(_:String,locale:NSLocale,_:CVarArgType...)` and 2) `NSNumber` for `%d` is not appropriate.